# Compressing a file

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, stringbuilder

I want to accomplish a program which can take a textfile and make the size smaller.  So far it replaces all the double character occurrences, and now I want to replace "ou" with "1".

I've tried with an if-statement, but it doesn't seem to work quite well.

My method is below:

```
public String compressIt (String input)
    {
        int length = input.length(); // length of input
        int ix = 0;                  // actual index in input
        char c;                      // actual read character
        int cCounter;                // occurrence counter of actual character
        String ou = "ou";
        StringBuilder output =       // the output
                new StringBuilder(length);

        // loop over every character in input
        while(ix < length)
        {
            // read character at actual index then increments the index
            c = input.charAt(ix++);
            // we count one occurrence of this character here
            cCounter = 1;

            // while not reached end of line and next character
            // is the same as previously read
            while(ix < length && input.charAt(ix) == c)
            {
                // inc index means skip this character
                ix++;
                // and inc character occurence counter
                cCounter++;
            }


            if (input.charAt(ix) == 'o' && input.charAt(++ix) == 'u' && ix < length - 1)
            {
                output.append("1");
            }

            // if more than one character occurence is counted
            if(cCounter > 1)
            {
                // print the character count
                output.append(cCounter);
            }

            // print the actual character
            output.append(c);
        }
        // return the full compressed output
        return output.toString();
    }
```

It's this lines of code I'm referring to.

```
if (input.charAt(ix) == 'o' && input.charAt(ix + 1) == 'u')
            {
                output.append("1");
            }
```

What I want to do: Replace characters. I got a text-file which contains "Alice In Wonderland". When my looping through all characters sees an 'o' and an 'u' (like "You"), I want to replace the characters so it looks like: "Y1".

Regards

Comment: Shouldn't that be `++ix`? What is the value of `ix` at the start, and how long is the string?

Comment: Firstly, I think you mean to do `++ix` not `ix++` -- the way you have it now, you're checking the same index each time, and only _after_ the statement incrementing `ix`. But once you fix that, what happens if `input` is a string that ends in `o`? That is, `if (charAt(ix) == 'o')` is true, and `ix` is the last index of the string? Or for that matter, what happens if `ix` is itself past the last index, due to a previous iteration of the loop you're presumably in?

Comment: Oh, I think you just want `ix + 1`, not `++ix` or `ix++` (which both modify the value of `ix`).

Comment: I did try with ix + 1, and that gave me the same exception :-/

Comment: Check out the updated version. I inserted the whole method to avoid misunderstanding

Comment: It seems like you want to do some kind of frequency calculation since you are appending the frequencies of each letter. But, you say that just want to replace occurrences of "ou", for which, st.replaceAll("on", "1") would suffice. Can you please update your question to cover all the cases?

Comment: This is a program, which should compress the file size. I've already replaced double character occurrences, which the program does now, but I can't seem to get the "ou" replacement settled.

Answer (score 1):

So most likely you're trying loop from ix = 0 to the length of the string.

First of all my guess is that youre looping up and including string.length(). Which doesnt work, charAt is 0 indexed aka
"abc" has a charAt 0, 1 and 2 but not 3 which gives the error you describe.

Second of all the line you showed uses `input.charAt (ix++)` which does the following: get the char at position ix (old value) and after that, update the value ix to ix + 1, if you want ix to be updated before the surrounding charAt you'd have to write `input.charAt(++ix)`

Third of all there is a String.replace function, input.replace("abc", "def") will work great for simple replacements, for more complicated replacements, consider using regex.

Comment: Thank you for that respons. Was a great little lesson. How would you use the replace in this case? Check out the updated post :)

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the charAt method. You need to change your if condition to run it till length-1. It is failing in the last case as it is going out array.

```
for(int i=0; i<inputString.length() - 1; i++)
        {
            char temp = inputString.charAt(i);
            char blah = inputString.charAt(i+1);
            System.out.println("temp: "+ temp);
            System.out.println("blah: "+ blah);
        }
```

This works for me!

Comment: Why has it nothing to do with the charAt() method? :-) Just wondering, so I can make better titles next time. But check out the updated post.

Comment: @AlexanderFalk Two things: You are looping yourself out of limit as your while condition runs till ix < length and you are using ix++. If you use ++ix and make a check on this condition so that it doesn't gets executed last time, it will work.

Comment: Like adding in the if statement : && ix < length - 1  ? :) Thanks for the respond